# User Input Restriction

Tags: java

I am making a simple program and it is already working I already restrict the user to input negative numbers and over 100 numbers, what I need to do now is restrict the user to input Strings or char or Symbol, everything that is not a number, but I simply don't know how can someone please help me :).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Average {
public static void main(String[]args) {
    double Math;
    double Science;
    double Filipino;
    double English;
    double sum;
    double average;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    do{
    System.out.println("Please enter your grade in Math");
    Math = input.nextDouble();
    if(Math<0||Math>100){
        System.out.println("You entered "+Math+", which is an invalid grade, please try again.");}
    }
    while(Math<0||Math>100);

    do{
    System.out.println("Please enter your grade in Science");
    Science = input.nextDouble();
    if(Science<0||Science>100){
        System.out.println("You entered "+Science+", which is an invalid grade, please try again.");}
    }
    while(Science<0||Science>100);

    do{
    System.out.println("Please enter your grade in Filipino");
    Filipino = input.nextDouble();
    if(Filipino<0||Filipino>100){
        System.out.println("You entered "+Filipino+", which is an invalid grade, please try again.");}
    }
    while(Filipino<0||Filipino>100);

    do{
    System.out.println("Please enter your grade in English");
    English = input.nextDouble();
    if(English<0||English>100){
        System.out.println("You entered "+English+", which is an invalid grade, please try again.");}
    }
    while(English<0||English>100);

    sum = Math + Science + Filipino + English;
    average = sum / 4;

    System.out.println("Your total average is: "+average);

    if(average>=75){
        System.out.println("Remarks: Passed");}
    else{
        System.out.println("Remarks: Failed");}
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your input reading inside a try block and use the following catch block.

```
catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    //handle exception here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use java's in-built check for that `NumberFormatException`.

```
String s = input.next();
double value = 0.0;
try{
    value = Double.parseDouble(s);
    //your code logic
} catch(NumberFormatException e){
    System.out.println("Please Enter a number");
    //your logic to take input again
}
```

Comment: @KenjinSanMiguel We are here to help guide you, not spoon feed you, mate. Yes, put your whole do while loop in the try block

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
try{
do{
System.out.println("Please enter your grade in Math");
Math = input.nextDouble();
if(Math<0||Math>100){
    System.out.println("You entered "+Math+", which is an invalid grade, please try again.");}
}
while(Math<0||Math>100);}
catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
```

}